# The Actual Process & Reason Of Performing Kanya Puja during Navratra?

Tags: rituals

The traditional Kanjak Puja or Kanya Puja is also an important feature of Navratras. At the time of Pooja, the girl is considered to be an ‘avatar’ of Durga on earth and worshipped. Kanya Pujan or Kanjak Pujan is performed with a belief that young girls are the replica of Goddess Durga. The devotees invite girls at homes and offer ‘bhog’. The faith is that Goddess Durga, who is worshipped in nine avatars during Navratri, gets pleased by `KanyaPujan’. This ritual is celebrated on the eighth and ninth day of Navratri. The nine names of the Goddesses the nine girls can be represented as:-
1. Kumarika
2. Trimurti
3. Kalyani
4. Rohini
5. Kali
6. Chandika
7. Shanbhavi
8. Durga
9. Subhadra
However, I am not aware of the actual process, rituals & reason of performing Kanya Puja during 'Navratra'.

Answer (score 2):

Navaratra was first celebrated long ago by 'Sati' to see if 'Shiv' loved her. That day at night there was celebration and many more girls were worshipping him.Sati was with her dance teacher 'Madhurika' and she told her that 'shiv' loved her. After the night was over Shiva said that day will be celebrated as navaratra from then and all the single girls on that day will find her lover. Since Sati or 'Durga' won her love that day, kanyas today are considered DURGA and worshipped.

Comment: Kindly provide sources.